# Get registered schema by ID/subject with in connector

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to get the registered schema from with in a source connector ? I have a static schema registered in schema registry and need to get that schema from connector and pass it to SourceRecord.

I used CachedSchemaRegistryClient to get the schema using schema id , but it returned an Avro Schema. So i have to convert this in to org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema. Please provide some pointers on this.

Or any other way in connector where i can do the same directly with out using CachedSchemaRegistryClient ?

Thank You,
Sreejith

Comment: Hi Sreehith, 

Did you find a way to do this. I am too at this point and want to convert `com.apache.avro.Schema` -> `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a rest call to the schema registry to do the lookup. However this is a pretty nonstandard use of a connector. You might be better off doing this kind of lookup in a converter.

Comment: Thanks @dawsaw. I am able to do that and i will get an Avro Schema. Not i have to convert that to Connect Schema and pass that in SourceRecord. Now searching for a way to do that.